# How to use JSON in pysnmp

Tags: python, pysnmp

Hi im looking for a way to use json as array of oids in pysnmp
currently my inout data is like this:

```
(
    # 1-st target (SNMPv1 over IPv4/UDP)
    ( cmdgen.CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
      cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
      ( cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0),
        cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysLocation', 0) ) ),
    # 2-nd target (SNMPv2c over IPv4/UDP)
    ( cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
      cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
      ( cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0),
        cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysLocation', 0) ) ),
    # 3-nd target (SNMPv3 over IPv4/UDP)
    ( cmdgen.UsmUserData('usr-md5-des', 'authkey1', 'privkey1'),
      cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
      ( cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0),
        cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysLocation', 0) ) ),
    # 4-th target (SN MPv3 over IPv6/UDP)
    ( cmdgen.UsmUserData('usr-md5-none', 'authkey1'),
      cmdgen.Udp6TransportTarget(('::1', 161)),
      ( cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0),
        cmdgen.MibVariable('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysLocation', 0) ) ),
    # N-th target
    # ...
)
```

and i call it like this:

```
for authData, transportTarget, varNames in targets:
    acmdGen.getCmd(
        authData, transportTarget, varNames,
        # User-space callback function and its context
        (cbFun, (authData, transportTarget)),
        lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
    )
```

it would be great if someone could provide a sample.

Comment: I don't have any snmp experience, but I have used json with python.  Could you clarify a little?  Do you want to store the returns of all instantiations of the array above? (The one with all the `cmdgen.Object` stuff).  Or do you want to json that array itself?

Comment: i want to use JSON object instead of the first code segment which define snmp information that will be used in second code segment

Comment: And what is the reason for using a JSON object over a python dict?  Are you trying to flatfile some data or share with other languages or something?  Everything in JSON is a string, so it will take some extra effort to JSON python objects.  You could make a JSON object and use it to look up the parameters you are instantiating the `cmdgend.Object`s with.  Would that help? I'm still a little confused  :)

Comment: there is IPC with node.js. i have a JSON data there and i prefer to use it as is instead of converting it to something else. is it clear now? :)